# Reading data per column of unicode file in python

Tags: python, unicode

I have a text file below stored in unicode, i am trying to retrieve the data per column and put in a list for later calculation. my code is below. it is not reading it as a line but as charaters

Text file

```
DateρOrderIDρProductIDρUserIDρAccMngrIDρQuantity
2013-01-01ρ1000ρ1ρ1ρ10
2013-01-01ρ1000ρ2ρ1ρ5
```

Code

```
import codecs

fhand = codecs.open('Transaction_logs.txt',encoding='utf-8')
inp = fhand.read()
#print inp

for line in inp:
  print repr(line)
```

Sample Output

```
u'\r', u'\n, u'2',u'0'
```

Comment: I think you want `readlines`, not `read` (or `for line in inp.split('\n')`). You should look into [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), too.

Comment: actually maybe `for line in fhand:` would suffice ?

Answer (score 1):

`file.read()` reads the whole content as a single string, so your `for` loop iterate on the individual characters. All you need is to iterate on the file directly, ie:

```
fhand = codecs.open('Transaction_logs.txt',encoding='utf-8')
for line in fhand:
  print repr(line)
```

Now given your file's format, you possibly want to use the builtin `csv` module instead - it can handle any delimiter and properly take care of quite a lot of low-level boring details.

Comment: I made the changes as sugested ..the output is belowu'\ufeffDate\u03c1OrderID\u03c1ProductID\u03c1UserID\u03c1AccMngrID\u03c1Quantity'
u'2013-01-01\u03c11000\u03c11\u03c11\u03c110'
u'2013-01-01\u03c11000\u03c12\u03c11\u03c15'
u'2013-01-01\u03c11001\u03c11\u03c11\u03c11'                      how do I remove the \u0321111 code in the column, i have also imported csv. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dont print the representation, print the unicode string itself. As for your other questions: splitting a string on a delimiter is Python 101 and clearly documented (hint: python strings are objects and they have quite a few useful methods), and the `csv` module if fully documented.

Comment: Pls help me out here                                                  import codecs
import csv

fhand = open('Transaction_logs2.txt')

for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    #print repr(line)

columns = line.split(',')
print columns
                                                                    Only the last row is applying in a list, my intention is for all the roles to apply in a list                                      this is output ['2013-01-01', '1001', '1', '2', '1', '1']
                                                                    Sorry for d bother, i am a newbie

Comment: Comments are not the place to post code (hint : you can edit your question), and being a newbie doesn't mean you shouldn't read the doc. Also in the snippet you posted fields are obviously not separated by a comma...

Answer (score 0):

That's an odd separator, but this is all you need.  I noticed your input file had a BOM character also.  using `utf-8-sig` automatically recognizes and strips it from the input,

```
with codecs.open('Transaction_logs.txt',encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.strip().split(u'\u03c1')
```

Output:

```
[u'Date', u'OrderID', u'ProductID', u'UserID', u'AccMngrID', u'Quantity']
[u'2013-01-01', u'1000', u'1', u'1', u'10']
[u'2013-01-01', u'1000', u'2', u'1', u'5']
```

Note that the `csv` module doesn't do Unicode so well without some additional help.  For example, in my testing it only allows 1-character delimiters and is not Unicode-aware internally, and your delimiter encodes to 3 bytes.